# Dynamically calculated zero padding in format string in python

Tags: python, string-formatting

So I know that `"%02d to %02d"%(i, j)` in Python will zero pad `i` and `j`.

But, I was wondering if there is any way to dynamically zero pad in a format string (I have a list of numbers and I want the zero pad size to be equal to the longest number in that list).

I know that I could use `zfill`, but I was hoping I could do the entire thing in a format string.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use the `str.format()` method of string formatting instead:

```
'{number:0{width}d}'.format(width=2, number=4)
```

Demo:

```
>>> '{number:0{width}d}'.format(width=2, number=4)
'04'
>>> '{number:0{width}d}'.format(width=8, number=4)
'00000004'
```

The [`str.format()` formatting specification](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) allows for multiple passes, where replacement fields can fill in parameters for formatting specifications.

In the above example, the hard-coded padding width specification would look like:

```
'{:02d}'.format(4)
```

or

```
'{number:02d}'.format(number=4)
```

with a named parameter. I've simply replaced the `2` width specifier with another replacement field.

To get the same effect with old-style `%` string formatting you'd need to use the `*` width character:

```
'%0*d' % (width, number)
```

but this can only be used with a tuple of values (dictionary formatting is not supported) and only applies to the field width; other parameters in the formatting do not support dynamic parameters.

Comment: Is there a way to achieve the same result (dynamically calculated padding) when using f-strings?

Comment: @albert it works exactly the same way using f-strings. Given `number, width = 4, 2`, `f"{number:0{width}d}"` produces `'04'`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible

```
>>> print "%0*d" % (5, 4)
00004
>>> print "%0*d" % (10, 4)
0000000004
```